# TCL problem: imported function get bracket({}) added around the "text"

Tags: tcl

I have a "library" type file that where I define a namespace and export some functions to "print" debug info or "trace" info in TCL.

```
proc cputs  { args } {
    puts "Test= $args"
}
```

I import this function in multiple other files.  When I use it everything is fine except it add bracket to the output.

Like if I call `cputs "Hi there"` it will output `{Hi there}` instead of `Hi there`.

Can't find anything to explain that.  I would like to get ride of those brackets.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to pass an arbitrary, unknown numbers of arguments to your `cproc`, do not use `args` (which has a special meaning as a parameter name), but `msg`, for instance.

```
proc cputs  {msg} {
    puts "Test= $msg"
}
```

See also [`proc` documentation](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm):

> If the last formal argument has the name “args”, then a call to the
>   procedure may contain more actual arguments than the procedure has
>   formal arguments. In this case, all of the actual arguments starting
>   at the one that would be assigned to args are combined into a list (as
>   if the list command had been used); this combined value is assigned to
>   the local variable args.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take an arbitrary number of arguments (since `args` is a special name), you should `join` or `concat` things before printing. These two options differ in their treatment of extra whitespace; use the one that suits you.

```
proc cputs { args } {
    puts "Test= [join $args]"
}

cputs "Hello there   " "   from an example"
# Test= Hello there      from an example
```

```
proc cputs { args } {
    puts "Test= [concat {*}$args]"
}

cputs "Hello there   " "   from an example"
# Test= Hello there from an example
```

Comment: Thanks.I did test the {*} but it wasn't working.  Found out it was available in a later version.  We use 8.4.  I'll try other option before trying to update to a new version of TCL...